# ObjectDataSource has no values to insert multiple insert params

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I have a class `DocumentRuleViewModel` which has the following function definitions

```
Insert(ReplaceRule Obj, int DocumentId)
Select(int DocumentId)
Update(ReplaceRule Obj)
Delete(ReplaceRule Obj)
```

The `select`, `update`, and `delete` functions work just fine with my `objectdatasource`, however the `insert` does not wish to work and keeps telling me that the object is empty

The error message I am recieving is `ObjectDataSource 'dsDocumentSourceRules' has no values to insert. Check that the 'values' dictionary contains values.`

There are a few questions like this one however none that I've found that assist in the issue from what I could make out of them.

The code I am using is below

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="gvDocumentRules" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dsDocumentSourceRules" KeyFieldName="ID"
    ClientInstanceName="gdDocRules">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True" VisibleIndex="0" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" ShowEditButton="True">
        </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ID" VisibleIndex="1"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="TypeID" VisibleIndex="2"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="SearchFor" VisibleIndex="3">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn><dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ReplaceText" VisibleIndex="4"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="OrderIndex" VisibleIndex="5"></dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="dsDocumentSourceRules" 
    DataObjectTypeName="DocumentBuilder.Models.ReplaceRule" 
    DeleteMethod="Delete" 
    InsertMethod="Insert" 
    SelectMethod="RetrieveRulesForDocument" 
    TypeName="DocumentBuilder.ViewModel.DocumentRuleViewModel" 
    UpdateMethod="Update">
       <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="obj" Type="Object"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DocumentTypeIDTextBox" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="0" Name="DocumentId" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DocumentTypeIDTextBox" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="0" Name="DocumentId" Type="Int32"></asp:ControlParameter>
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Any Thoughts or solutions is appreciated. I feel as if I am missing something fundamental

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the DevExpress team for their reply on their site

> Thank you for the clarification. According to the answers at
>   ObjectDataSource has no values to insert, it seems that it is
>   impossible to pass additional parameters to the Insert method using
>   this approach. I suggest you use the ObjectDataSource.OnInserting
>   event handler and invoke the custom Insert method. Do not forget to
>   set the e.Cancel property to false, otherwise, the method you've
>   specified in the InsertMethod property will be called. Please refer to
>   the following code snippet and the attached project.

```
   protected void dsDocumentSourceRules_Inserting(object sender,
     ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e) {
         ReplaceRule rule = (ReplaceRule)e.InputParameters["obj"];
        DocumentRuleViewModel.Insert(rule, Int32.Parse(DocumentTypeIDTextBox.Value.ToString()));
         e.Cancel = true; }
```

...

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Insert, true)] public static
    void Insert(ReplaceRule obj, Int32 DocumentId) {
         obj.ID = data.Count;
         obj.TypeID = DocumentId;
         data.Add(obj); }
```